# Can you use an array for MessageEmbed#setDescription?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have created a discord bot of mine just as a fun project. I am trying to make a todo list (the bot responds with a made todo list once I type a `-todo command`). I want to put an array in an embed message box.

Can I use `.setDescription(array[])`? Or is there another way to display it in the embed box? It works with text messages but not as an embed.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'todolist',
  description: 'Sends a to do list in the channel',
  execute(message, args) {
    let i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < todolist.length; i++){
      message.channel.send(`${todolist[i]}`);
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Discord.js v13

No, you cannot use `.setDescription(array)`. Discord.js v13 [stopped converting non-strings into strings](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#strings) for these sorts of methods to avoid `[object Object]` and other undesired outcomes.

You need to convert the array into a string first (e.g. `.setDescription(array.join('\n'))` replicates the Discord.js v12 behaviour).

### Discord.js v12

Yes, you can use `.setDescription(array)`.

[`setDescription`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setDescription) accepts a [`StringResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/StringResolvable) and uses the resolved string as the embed description. This behaves in the same way as `TextBasedChannel#send`: arrays are joined with a new line.